# Can't Include External Javascript In File

Tags: javascript, html, xampp

I'm new to PHP and VERY, VERY new to any sort of server administration. I'm running from XAMPP 3.1.0 for Windows and using PHP Version 5.4.

My PHP script is executing just fine, but for whatever reason I can't seem to include external js files like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
```

However, I can do this with no problems.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("some alert");
</script>
```

Does anyone know whats going on?

[**EDIT**: Here's my folder structure. The path to my files is:
C:\xampp\htdocs\AllocatedSpendingPlan\ - they both live at the root.]

[image: Folder Structure]

And here is my file:

[**EDIT**: I removed the code from the body of the script tag with the src attribute, and it still isn't working.]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("working");
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        There is stuff here.
    </body>
</html>
```

When I look at the Net tab in Firefox, I show that the file has been downloaded, but none of the scripts are executing, and the file itself isn't loaded when I go to debug.

Here's the script debugger, showing no file loaded:

[image: Firefox's Script Debugger, Not Showing Loaded Script]

Finally, this is my Net tab, showing that the file has been downloaded:

[image: Firefox's Net Tab, Showing That The File Was Located and Downloaded]

[**EDIT**: Fixed. It was a mistake in my namespace declaration. I declared my var as a function when it should have been an object literal.]

Here is the correct code. Everything else is fine.

```
var Core = {
    namespace: function(ns){
        var parts = ns.split("."),
        object = this,
        i, len;
        for (i=0, len=parts.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (!object[parts[i]]) {
                object[parts[i]] = {};
            }
            object = object[parts[i]];
        }
        return object;
    }
};

Core.namespace("Budgeting.Tools.AllocatedSpending");

Core.Budgeting.Tools.AllocatedSpending = function(){
    return {
        greet: function(){
            alert("hello");
        }
    };
};

var d = new Core.Budgeting.Tools.AllocatedSpending();
d.greet();
```

Comment: Are you sure you have the right path to the javascript file?

Answer (score 1):

#### After seeing your screenshots,

1. When you use a `src=""` attribute, you are supposed to leave the body of the `<script>` tag empty. So remove that `alert("I am here, aren't you!")` from there.
2. Your `core.js` is not found at the path. Let us know the folder path.

Comment: I added the script to the body to see if it was being executed at all. I removed it and it still doesn't work. The path to the javascript file (from my local machine) is: C:\xampp\htdocs\AllocatedSpendingPlan\core.js and the html file is C:\xampp\htdocs\AllocatedSpendingPlan\index.html.

Comment: OKay. In that case, if you are using Firefox, press `Ctrl + U` and click on the `core.js`.

Comment: Done. I can see the source of the file, it just isn't available to my page. It doesn't work in IE either.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your console for errors (CTRL+SHIFT+I for Chrome/Windows).
- It's possibly a 404 error or an error in your `core.js` file. Make sure the path is correct: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/to/core.js"></script>`
- The script is possibly being included too early/late. To test this, make sure that `<script>` block is in the `<head>`

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple coding error. I declared my namespace as a function  instead of an object literal. The code should have read:

```
var Core = {
    namespace: function(ns){
        var parts = ns.split("."),
        object = this,
        i, len;
        for (i=0, len=parts.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (!object[parts[i]]) {
                object[parts[i]] = {};
            }
            object = object[parts[i]];
        }
        return object;
    }
};
```

Instead of:

```
var Core = function () {
    namespace: function(ns){
        var parts = ns.split("."),
        object = this,
        i, len;
        for (i=0, len=parts.length; i < len; i++) {
            if (!object[parts[i]]) {
                object[parts[i]] = {};
            }
            object = object[parts[i]];
        }
        return object;
    }
};
```

Talk about not seeing the forest for the trees...