# Why do script tags need to be left empty when importing a JS file?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning JavaScript along with HTML and CSS. I wrote up JavaScript file, Primes.js, that contains a few prime-finding related functions for testing.

To test out using external .js files, I wrote up the following HTML file:

```
...
<body>
    <script src="Primes.js">
        console.log("Loaded...");

        var n = 13;
        alert(n + " is prime?: " + isPrime(n));

        console.log("Ending...");
    </script>
</body>
...
```

But it never executed the statements within the script block.

After looking around, I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13656071/3000206), and changed the body to:

```
...
<body>
    <script src="Primes.js"></script>
    <script>
        console.log("Loaded...");

        var n = 13;
        alert(n + " is prime?: " + isPrime(n));

        console.log("Ending...");
    </script>
</body>
...
```

And magically, it worked as expected. It seems odd requiring an empty script tag to import a file.

Why require that the script tag importing the .js file be empty? Are/were there consequences if scripts were sources in the same tag they were used?

Comment: That's the way the standard is defined. There's no "reason" why it's better / worse, that's just the way it is.

Comment: I don't think language designer's design choices are completely random. There must be a reason for this restriction.

Comment: I didn't imply it's random, but if your question is an attempt to guess what the reasons were then it's off topic for SO.

Comment: I doubt it was random. Personally I see supporting what you mentioned as confusing. What executes first, the src or the stuff between the tags? Meaning does the file in the src get inserted before the body or after it? Having two separate tags removes any ambiguity. I don't know if you'll find an authoritative answer to this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As written in [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/scripting-1.html) the content inside the script is supposed to use for documentation of the script when `src` attribute is present.

> If a script element's src attribute is specified, then the contents of the script element, if any, must be such that the value of the text IDL attribute, which is derived from the element's contents, matches the documentation production in the following ABNF, the character set for which is Unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you were not importing script from another file, you would type the script between the script tags.  But since you are importing by declaring a `src`, the script in the file you are importing is treated as if it were inserted between the (empty) script tags by your browser.

Answer (score 0):

The src attribute designates that the script should be imported. The rendering engine will ignore anything placed between the script tags when it sees an src attribute.

Placing text between script tags without the src attribute tells the rendering engine to runs it as inline script.

So do your import, then add your inline scripting between a new set of script tags.